# Why do slide transitions in beamer not work with XeLaTeX?

Tags: beamer, xetex

I try to use some slide transitions in `beamer` with `XeLaTex` but it does not work. Why does this happens and how can I deal with it? But it works when I use slide transitions in beamer with PDFLaTeX. XeLaTeX was used for dealing with a lot of Chinese characters since it is flexible for font selection. Here is my MWE:

```
% !Mode:: "TeX:UTF-8"
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{fontspec,xunicode,xltxtra}

\useoutertheme{infolines}
\usetheme{Darmstadt}

\begin{document}

\title{Example}
\institute{CUMT}
\author{xiao}


\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Example of Transboxin}
\transboxin
Frame Body Text
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Example of Transboxin}
\transboxin
Frame Body Text No2

It does not work. Do you see it?
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Any help will be really appreciated!

Well, if it can not be solved I will ignor slide transitions which do not affect my presentation.

Comment: For me works perfectly under evince viewer. Which one do you use?

Comment: In addition, which versions of `beamer` and XeTeX are you using?

Comment: HI i've tried your code and it's perfectly working on my pc. I use latest version of miktex. How did you compile your document ?

Comment: @Claudio Fiandrino I use win7, TeXLive2011 and Adobe Reader9.0

Comment: @Joseph Wright I use the beamer which comes with TeXLive2011

Comment: @xiaodaxialiang The version of `beamer` (or any package) is not fixed in a TeX Live release. In your `.log` file there will be a line telling you which `beamer` version is in use.

Comment: @Swiss12000 OMG! I can not believe that I do not get these transitions yet. I use win7+TeXLive2011+Adobe Reader 9.0, and the version of 'beamer' comes with TeXLive2011. Should I update 'beamer'?

Comment: @JosephWright Yes, here is the copy "Document Class: beamer 2010/06/21 development version 3.10 A class for typesett
ing presentations (rcs-revision a6b1a8434d30)" and "Package: beamerbasemodes 2010/05/01 (rcs-revision efa082c6111d)"

Comment: @xiaodaxialiang This is 'works for me' with both version 3.10 and the current release. Displaying the transitions is down to your viewer, and there have been no changes to the code in `beamer` in this area for some time.

Comment: @JosephWright Thanks a lot. I have no choice but to ignore these effect.

Comment: Given that this is as likely to be about the PDF viewer as about TeX, could you upload the PDF that shows the problem?  You'll have to upload it somewhere else (if you load it here it will get converted to PNG which wouldn't help) and then link to it.  If no-one can reproduce the problem, no-one can help!  Otherwise, we'll probably close this as "too localised" to indicate that at this time, we're unable to help you.